# what is 'disasm.cpp' used for in Detours? I don't understand the declaration of class CDetourDis

Tags: c++, disassembly, detours

There are so many macros definitions,the comment says，"These macros define common uses of `nFixedSize`, `nFixedSize16`, `nModOffset`, `nRelOffset`, `nFlagBits`, `pfCopy`." what does it mean?

I think this may be the CPU instruction set, so I tried to look up some information from Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual, I didn't find any information about `0F`, `0F00`, `0F78`, `0FB8` and so on.

```
// nFlagBits flags.
enum {
    DYNAMIC     = 0x1u,
    ADDRESS     = 0x2u,
    NOENLARGE   = 0x4u,
    RAX         = 0x8u,
};
// ModR/M Flags
enum {
    SIB         = 0x10u,             
    RIP         = 0x20u,
    NOTSIB      = 0x0fu,
};
```

// part of macro definitions, more details: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/blob/master/src/disasm.cpp

```
#define ENTRY_CopyBytes1Address     5, 3, 0, 0, ADDRESS, &CDetourDis::CopyBytes
#define ENTRY_CopyBytes3Dynamic     3, 3, 0, 0, DYNAMIC, &CDetourDis::CopyBytes
#define ENTRY_CopyF2                ENTRY_DataIgnored &CDetourDis::CopyF2
#define ENTRY_CopyF3                ENTRY_DataIgnored &CDetourDis::CopyF3
#define ENTRY_Copy0F                ENTRY_DataIgnored &CDetourDis::Copy0F
#define ENTRY_Copy0F78              ENTRY_DataIgnored &CDetourDis::Copy0F78
```

I want to know what these are ,and what's the use of this `disasm.cpp` file, especially the function `DetourCopyInstruction(PVOID pDst, PVOID *ppDstPool, PVOID pSrc, PVOID *ppTarget, LONG *plExtra)`?

Comment: When hooking a function, the first 5 bytes of that function must be overwritten with a `jmp`. The location where jumped to must contain the first bytes of the original function. However, since x86 is a variable length instruction set, it may be more than 5 bytes. Therefore, the length must be calculated, so that e.g. 7 bytes are copied, because the first instructions are 7 bytes (not 5). The disassembler engine is there just to calculate the exact length of instructions, which requires disassembly.